# MIPS program not printing string

Tags: assembly, memory, mips, memory-address, mars-simulator

### Working code

Following is a simple program which prints *Hello guys*:

```
.data
myMessage: .asciiz "Hello guys\n"

.text

li $v0, 4
la $a0, myMessage
syscall
```

Output:

```
pam@g3:~/fuzzy-robot$ java -jar Mars4_5.jar main.asm
MARS 4.5  Copyright 2003-2014 Pete Sanderson and Kenneth Vollmar

Hello guys
```

### Similar code but not working

But when I adding some extra statements for handling memory locations, this code doesn't work:

```
.data
myMessage: .asciiz "Hello guys\n"

.text
li $t8,268500992
li $t0, 199
sw $t0,0($t8)

li $v0, 4
la $a0, myMessage
syscall
```

Output:

```
pam@g3:~/fuzzy-robot$ java -jar Mars4_5.jar main.asm
MARS 4.5  Copyright 2003-2014 Pete Sanderson and Kenneth Vollmar

Ç
```

I want to know why it is not working the second time?

You can download the **Mars4_5.jar** file from [here](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/MARS_4_5_Aug2014/Mars4_5.jar).

Comment: Because you overwrote the first four bytes of the string. You should be able to see this easily in the simulator by looking at the Data Segment view.

Comment: Moral of the story: don't try to access arbitrary memory locations without knowing that it's ok to do so.

Comment: Hey, we are given a project. And we are using these memory locations for our stack to store variables. That's why those statements are written. 

Can you tell me an alternative?

Comment: Use `.space` to reserve the start of the .data section for your absolute addressing that ignores symbols.  So you store your string constants later in .data.  Or just use symbols for addressing so you don't have to match up your .data section against manual numeric addressing.  Or use actual stack space relative to `$sp` to store local variable.

Comment: What is this address location `268500992`? The program works fine with `268501012`. Now I am a bit confused about what to ask for. I will do more research on this number and update the question accordingly.

Comment: Do  you have a hex calculator?  Look at that decimal value in hex and you might recognize the address if you poke around the simulator's data view.